# How to use typedef to alias C++ arrays?

Tags: c++, c

when using typedef for arrays, it is used as

```
typedef int Color[3];
```

it is very counter-intuitive for me.

why not `typedef int[3] Color[3]?`

Comment: What is the question here exactly?

Comment: FYI, hiding an array type behind a typedef is usually considered bad practice, because it has the potential to be extremely confusing.

Comment: I can't be sure, but I think OP intended the last line to be `typedef int[3] Color;`. The way it is now doesn't make any kind of sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`typedef` looks *exactly* like a normal vairable declaration, and that happens to be how an array declaration looks in C (and inherited into C++):

```
int foo[3]; // Array of three int
typedef int FooT[3]; // typedef for array of three int.
```

Comment: As an aside, note that "normal variable declaration" in C/C++ can be ridiculous, so even though `typedef` mimics it, that doesn't mean the result will look reasonable.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that's just the way the language is defined.  If it's helpful, the `typedef` syntax looks just like the declaration syntax:

```
int Color[3];
```

Would make an array of three integers, so:

```
typedef int Color[3];
```

Typedefs an array of three integers.

A convenient advantage of the syntax matching is that you can use a tool like [`cdecl(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/cdecl.1.html) to generate or explain them for you:

```
cdecl> explain int Color[3]
declare Color as array 3 of int
cdecl> declare Color as array 3 of int
int Color[3]
```

Answer (score 4):

Typedef simply works like a varaible definition and follows all the same rules (rules that are already established and known), with the only difference that instead of a variable name it denotes the type.

I would say, rather than implementing some new scheme (that would have to handle all the subtle things like, just for sake of example, pointers to arrays vs. arrays of pointers), using an existing scheme is the sensible choice.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using

```
typedef std::array<int,3> RGB_Type;
```

Which is in line with typedef-ing other C++ std containers.

(Sorry, C++ only, but that was mentionned in the title.)

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can create a syntax that does close to what you want:

```
template<typename T>
using type_def = T;

type_def<int[3]> colors;
```

At first glance, I would recommend against it: on the other hand, some really complex type declarations could be simplified a lot via this mechanism.  Getting rid of "placeholder" `typedef` in complex types whose purpose is only to make the final type look more readable.